# iFrame not working in jQuery Mobile (Phone Gap)

Tags: android, jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile

My code is:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageID">


    <div data-role="header"  data-position="fixed">
        <p>Directions</p>
    </div>


    <div data-role="content">

        <div style="width:100%; height:80%;">
            <iframe src="http://m.google.com"  seamless=""></iframe>     
        </div>

    </div> 

</div>
```

But when I come to this page Google is not loaded. I'm trying on Samsung Galaxy S Android phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont use iFrame with JQM on mobile phones. iFrame is not going to work with some built-in android browsers. Have you tried to test it on mobile chrome or firefox browser?

Worst case scenario use [this](http://a.shinynew.me/post/19786775381/bridging-the-phonegap-childbrowser-plugin) component instead. It is a phonegap plugin used to show new browser window.

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/7tgaa/) example should work. I have tested it on my Galaxy S3.

```
<iframe style="width: 400px; height: 400px" src="http://m.google.com" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

Comment: its working in the system browser... but i want it to run in android

Comment: is there any other way to do the above action

Comment: No dude... its not working.... I guess S3 it will work bcoz it has a better web kit which even supports Page Transition Animations... But for Android 2.X its a problem... Is there any way to make it work in Android 2.X .... thanks

Answer (score 2):

this iframe work for me but having list problems

```
<iframe name="frame" src="http://google.com" frameborder="0" style="overflow:hidden;overflow-x:hidden;overflow-y:hidden;height:100%;width:100%;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px">
    </iframe>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be issue with blocking urls aswell.. 
If you are using phonegap build..add following lines to config.xml.

Reference Link: http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/#googtrans(en) Configurations block..

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
<allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
<allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
<allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
<allow-intent href="geo:*"/>
<platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*"/>
</platform>
<platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*"/>
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*"/>
</platform>
```

Make sure `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>` this one added..